# change evince gvfs metadata

Tags: ubuntu, metadata, gio

I found how to extract evince bookmarks using gvfs-info (https://askubuntu.com/questions/294285/where-are-evince-bookmarks-stored):

```
gvfs-info -a "metadata::evince::bookmarks" mypdf.pdf
```

How can I write that info to another identical pdf using python3 and gio or using gvfs-*something*?
(Original file lays in an UBUNTU 14 machine. Destination file lays in an UBUNTU 16 machine.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gvfs-set-attribute`:

```
gvfs-set-attribute new-file.pdf "metadata::evince::bookmarks" ${value}
```

where `${value}` is the GVariant string printed as the metadata value by `gvfs-info`.